# Error while parsing a date with Antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to parse dates using the following grammar:

```
grammar Dates;

formattedDate : (DATE '/' MONTH '/' year);
year : SHORT_YEAR | FULL_YEAR;

SHORT_YEAR : DIGIT DIGIT;
FULL_YEAR : ('19' | '20' | '21') DIGIT DIGIT;
DATE : (('0'..'2')? DIGIT) | '30' | '31';
MONTH : ('0'? DIGIT) | '11' | '12';

fragment DIGIT : ('0' .. '9');
```

But it fails to parse the values that I would expect to work. For example, an input of `11/04/2017` produces the error:

```
   line 1:0 mismatched input '11' expecting DATE
```

My first guess was that there are some values (1-12) that the lexer can't decide if it's a `DATE` or a `MONTH`, which is causing the problem. But when I tried to fix it by replacing them with parser rules instead, I had the same problem:

```
formattedDate : (dateNum '/' monthNum '/' year);

year : shortYear | fullYear;
shortYear : DIGIT DIGIT;
fullYear : ('19' | '20' | '21') DIGIT DIGIT;
dateNum : (('0'..'2')? DIGIT) | '30' | '31';
monthNum : ('0'? DIGIT) | '11' | '12';

fragment DIGIT : ('0' .. '9');
```

And it still seems to struggle on the first value, even it something like `31`, outside of the range of ambiguity.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's perhaps obvious why my first attempt doesn't work. The tokens overlap, so it is impossible for the lexer to be unambiguous. I've also seen a lot of advice on other questions here, saying not to try to put too many restrictions in the grammar, but rather leave those to be validation errors after parsing. But still, I would like to understand why this particular case won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, "the tokens overlap" (note `31` *is* ambiguous, it could be a short year). In cases like this, the longest possible matching lexer rule will be chosen. In case there are two or more matching with the same length, it'll choose the first (in the order they appear). *(I think I've read this some time ago in www.antlr.org)*

So just changing the order of the rules "solves" the problem – or pushes it forward (note `DATE` is before `SHORT_YEAR` and `MONTH`):

```
grammar Dates;

formattedDate : (DATE '/' MONTH '/' year);
year : SHORT_YEAR | FULL_YEAR;

DATE : (('0'..'2')? DIGIT) | '30' | '31';
SHORT_YEAR : DIGIT DIGIT;
FULL_YEAR : ('19' | '20' | '21') DIGIT DIGIT;
MONTH : ('0'? DIGIT) | '11' | '12';

fragment DIGIT : ('0' .. '9');
```

yields `line 1:3 mismatched input '04' expecting MONTH`.

---

A possible solution is to use lexer grammar modes:

DatesLexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar DatesLexer;

// Mode expecting DATE (default mode)
DATE : (('0'..'2')? DIGIT) | '30' | '31';
DATE_BAR : '/'
    -> pushMode(readingMonth);

// Mode expecting MONTH
mode readingMonth;
MONTH : ('0'? DIGIT) | '11' | '12';
MONTH_BAR : '/'
    -> popMode, pushMode(readingYear);

// Mode expecting *_YEAR
mode readingYear;
SHORT_YEAR : DIGIT DIGIT
    -> popMode;
FULL_YEAR : ('19' | '20' | '21') DIGIT DIGIT
    -> popMode;

fragment DIGIT : ('0' .. '9');
```

DatesParser.g4:

```
parser grammar DatesParser;

options { tokenVocab=DatesLexer; }

formattedDate : (DATE  DATE_BAR  MONTH  MONTH_BAR  year);
year : SHORT_YEAR | FULL_YEAR;
```

Result:

[image: A parse tree showing that the date 11/04/2017 was successfully parsed]

Only for reference:

```
> antlr4 DatesLexer.g4 [-o outDir]
> antlr4 DatesParser.g4 [-o outDir]
> [cd outDir]
> javac *.java
> grun Dates formattedDate -tokens <file> [-gui]
[@0,0:1='11',<1>,1:0]
[@1,2:2='/',<2>,1:2]
[@2,3:4='04',<3>,1:3]
[@3,5:5='/',<4>,1:5]
[@4,6:9='2017',<6>,1:6]
[@5,10:9='<EOF>',<-1>,1:10]
```